# How to select multiple value column where they are common on specified field?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, where-clause

I have a table named myindex.

SELECT * FROM `index` WHERE term in ("A","B")

But I want just highlighted rows.
this is my dictionary table. when user enter more than one keyword it should return its corresponding result. for example when user search "PHP Array" it should select all "PHP" term and also All "Array" terms that they have same doc_id.

Comment: What's wrong with adding `...AND doc_id='4'` or similar?

Comment: This table used for creating a dictionary. i wont use constant value like 4

Comment: Just assign the value to a PHP variable like `$doc_id = 4;` and then put `$doc_id` into the query instead of `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you say you want to select all rows wich contain an A or a B.

Whats the reason you want those 2 rows? is it because doc_id = 4?
in that case you need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM `index` WHERE term in ("A","B") AND `doc_id` = 4
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks so much.

Comment: How i can use variable value instead of 4, i want all term "A" and "B" common on `doc_id`

Comment: What language are you sending the query from?

Comment: The PHP language. i am trying to make search engine. this table is for my dictionary. when user enter more than one keyword i should return its corresponding result. for example when user search "PHP Array" i should select all "PHP" term and also All "Array" terms that they have same doc_id.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, am not sure how it will work but try this.

```
SELECT * FROM `index` WHERE term in ("A","B") AND doc_id = doc_id
```

Based in your desc about the search should be performanced to the same doc_id.
Try and let us what happend.

Comment: This work, but is not the exact result because of MySQL "in" clause. the "in" clause add "OR" between the values. i want something like "in" clause but add "AND" between the values.